# How can I return the ReturnType of functions from a list of parameters in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I have a main function `myMainFunction()` that takes in a list of functions as parameters. Each of these parameter functions can have a different return type.

I would like `myMainFunction` have its return type as the return types of the functions passed into it as parameters. However, I can't quite figure out to do it.

Here's what I have which doesn't seem to work:

```
const funcA = async (): string => "Hello";
const funcB = async (): {name: string, age: number} => ({ name: "Jane", age: 123 });

const myMainFunction = async <F extends () => ReturnType<F>>(...functions: F[]): Promise<ReturnType<F>[]> => {
  const res = await Promise.all(functions.map((fn) => fn()));
  return res;
};

// This doesn't work as values has a type of Promise<string>[]
// I'm expecting values to have a type of Promise<[string, {first: string, age: number }]>
const values = await myMainFunction(funcA, funcB);
```

What I have above doesn't work as the the variable `values` has a type of `Promise<string>[]`. For some reason, it only sees the return type of the first function in the parameters.

I'm expecting that `values` will have type of `Promise<[string, {first: string, age: number }]>` which are essentially the return types of `funcA()` and `funcB()`.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be *calling* the functions as you pass them into `myMainFunction`, should you? `myMainFunction` calls them...

Comment: The tuple part of this is defeating me. I should probably actually *read* a book on TypeScript. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh my! I must be drunk! Yes, the functions passed in as parameters shouldn't be calling them. I've updated my example again.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Haha! I don't know but I feel like this should be possible since the return types of the functions `funcA` and `funcB` are statically known beforehand. But I also don't know how to achieve it. It's quite confusing. I've tried another version of it like this: `async <T, F extends () => T>(...functions: F[]): Promise<ReturnType<F>[]` but it's not working as expected too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript has a special type for Array types  `T[number]`, so using this we can do->

```js
const funcA = async (): Promise<string> => "Hello";
const funcB = async (): Promise<{name: string, age: number}> => ({ name: "Jane", age: 123 });

const myMainFunction = async <T extends any[number][]> (...functions: T) => {
  const res = await Promise.all(functions);
  return res;
};

async function test() {
    const values = await myMainFunction(funcA(), funcB());
    // values[0]  string
    // values[1]  {name: string, age: number}
    console.log(values[1].age);
}
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMAgjAvDAhhAnsmACgEoAuGABQCcQBbASwgFMAeaK%20sAcwD4M%20ARAAkmAG1EgBAbgBQoSLETIAQhmx4CJctTqNWAbzBZaTcu05cANNi6mYYBLQBGTKgF8%206PoX33jdgQApLDAmAWssW3IARgAmAGYYN2JZOXBoGFpcAFksTgAxJGAoenA1HHxgGBYAFRgmAA8oJjAAEwhsMFwAbQdnVwBdboHvADpxpWLSyHIa4n4YfRkYGHkMqiYOzCwAdzzYHQZmUaxxQkmS9JTlmA2oBCowW83ZN1SKggvpmGboEkWbis1rAAG6nBCbcp7eiwLK5ApFS5gc5FFAkayTZQka4rFYAejxMDBoghEG6AAYBitzNxATACUTwZtutEqYsjCYzFAONwIlF7I4XO46WsQKImKMJFxCMTSSyBidbNc3EA)

The problem when you pass the functions, the map function loses the Type.  But we could just put them back in using `as`.  Thanks to @T.J.Crowder I used his MapToUnpromisedReturnType helper type and got this ->

```js
const funcA = async (): Promise<string> => "Hello";
const funcB = async (): Promise<{name: string, age: number}> => ({ name: "Jane", age: 123 });

type MapToUnpromisedReturnType<T extends Array<any>> = {
    [K in keyof T]: Awaited<ReturnType<T[K]>>;
};

const myMainFunction = async <T extends (() => Promise<any[number]>)[]> (...functions: T) => {
  const mapped = await functions.map(f => f());
  return mapped as MapToUnpromisedReturnType<T>;
};

async function test() {
    const values = await myMainFunction(funcA, funcB);
    // values[0]  string
    // values[1]  {name: string, age: number}
    console.log(values[1].age);
}
```

[Playground 2. passing promise functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.0-beta&ssl=19&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMAgjAvDAhhAnsmACgEoAuGABQCcQBbASwgFMAeaK%20sAcwD4M%20ARAAkmAG1EgBAbgBQoSLETIAQhmx4CJctTqNWAbzBZaTcu05cANNi6mYYBLQBGTKgF8%206PoX33jdgQApLDAmAWssW3IARgAmAGYYN2JZGShcAAcmGABZLAyAFRAAVTAMmgZmABMAJSYoBCowAszWApgmAA8oJjAqiBgUKiosXBYQ3B5PGH0ZGHmYAG0AaRhOGABrJlwQOBgCgF1yFAB3LHoeqpY6hqaWrJYClYOp2TdU%20WgYWlw8zgAxJDAKD0cBqHD4YAwR4dbq9fpEEj8SgVPTjMC4RYOZyuF7ERYvIgAOhJSmBoMg5AKxGRs3mn1gtHyWSq4LOF3gQJB4AgRKZGUIey88BIKTmMCo9UaYG%20zKYrJwuXyRVK5V01Ru0vubR4b1SEIIZO5Mp60CRdIWDJgADcsKIEEwBpgsOzGb9zmBAchjYKgShrGTlGKFjAAPShm12h0QRYABgO83M3HF83DkftjsW0QTMyMJjMUA43AiUXsjhc7hTME%20IFETCJEi4hFtGZj2aJkSYYrcMiAA)

ps: there may be a cleaner way, but it does seem to work nicely..

Just a slightly refactored version to take away helper ->

```js
const myMainFunction = async <T extends (() => Promise<any[number]>)[]> (...functions: T) => {
  return functions.map(f => f()) as {[K in keyof T]: Awaited<ReturnType<T[K]>>};
};
```

[Refactored](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.0-beta&ssl=7&ssc=1&pln=4&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMAgjAvDAhhAnsmACgEoAuGABQCcQBbASwgFMAeaK%20sAcwD4M%20ARAAkmAG1EgBAbgBQoSLETIAQhmx4CJctTqNWAbzBZaTcu05cANNi6mYYBLQBGTKgF8%206PoX33jdgQApLDAmAWssW3IARgAmAGYYN2JZOXBoGFpcAFksTgAxJGAoenA1HHxgGBYAFRgmAA8oJjAAEwgiEn5KGgZmFhDcAG0HZ1cAXR5iIcmiADoFpWLSyHIa4m79GRgYKiYoBCoweCKS9LnaLAAHQjhuuBINnBh9IYBpGE4YAGsmXBA7jVxuQUAB3PLNVosABK%200OYBquCurBq70mPDcskxMhkFQISzOx2a0C6Wx2O3kGQAblhRAgmB1MFhwfRYFlcgVTitbkUUNYlsoUttyQB6EUwGl0hlDAAM4x25m4wp2YoltPpECG0XlLyMJjMUA43AiUXsjhc7mVMEpIFETDmEi4hElGq14zmkSYQrcMiAA)

Comment: It's strange because in my IDE (IntelliJ), the variable `values` is just `any[]`. I'm using Typescript v4.4. Do I need a different version?

Comment: @Carven  Not sure, on Playground it's working fine.  I'll just check VS Code and see if it works there.

Comment: @Carven  Yes, VS Code works fine too, mouse over values and it gives you the types, and code complete etc..  Maybe something specific with IntelliJ..

Comment: I just tried changing the version in Playground to v4.4.4 and it doesn't work anymore. It's still pretty cool though! What does that `T[number]` really do? This is the first time I'm seeing this. I'm surprise you didn't even have to provide a return type to the `myMainFunction` and somehow it works in the Playground! I'm just wow!

Comment: @Carven Yes, 4.4, just noticed it not there too.. :)  `T[number]` extract's all the tuples out of an array as types.   Yes, the return type can be implicit as we now have given TS enough info to do it.  I always try and keep most my code using as much implicit types as possible.

Comment: Oh... I just realise that it doesn't work anymore when you use this instead: `await Promise.all(functions.map((fn) => fn()));` and assign `values` this way: `const values = await myMainFunction(funcA, funcB);`. Is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: Unfortunately the question was mixed-up when you posted your answer, it was both calling `funcA` and `funcB` when calling `myMainMethod` and also having `myMainMethod` calling them itself, via `map`. The question has since been edited to clarify that the callls should happen inside `myMainMethod`, which means isolating the types for the resulting tuple from the function return types (unwrapping the promise aspect). [Here's my attempt](https://tsplay.dev/wQ84YW) to build on what you've done above. It works, but it has...

Comment: ...a (fairly innocuous) type assertion I don't know how to get around. Please feel free to incorporate whatever helps into your answer. CC @Carven.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  That indeed is very helpful,  updating answer.

Comment: @Carven  Updated, kept both variants in, as that might be useful for others.

Answer (score 1):

## Old and not so clean version, don't use.

```
type ResolveFunction<T extends (...args: any) => any> = Awaited<ReturnType<T>>;
type ResolveFunctions<T extends [...((...args: any) => any)[]]> = T extends [
  infer Head,
  ...infer Tail
]
  ? Head extends (...args: any) => any
    ? Tail extends ((...args: any) => any)[]
      ? [ResolveFunction<Head>, ...ResolveFunctions<Tail>]
      : []
    : []
  : [];

const myMainFunction = async <T extends [...((...args: any) => any)[]]>(
  ...functions: T
): Promise<ResolveFunctions<T>> => {
  const res = await Promise.all(functions.map((fn) => fn()));
  return res as any;
};
```

## New version after looking at another answer.

```
type AsyncFunction = (...args: any) => Promise<any>;
type ResolveFunction<T extends AsyncFunction> = Awaited<ReturnType<T>>;
type ResolveFunctions<T extends AsyncFunction[]> = {
  [K in keyof T]: ResolveFunction<T[K]>;
};

const myMainFunction = async <T extends AsyncFunction[]>(
  ...functions: T
): Promise<ResolveFunctions<T>> => {
  const res = await Promise.all(functions.map((fn) => fn()));
  return res as any;
};
```

Comment: I certainly didn’t expect Typescript will need so much work just to get the return type of the functions in parameters. But I guess that’s just Typescript for now. Haha. Thanks a lot! Appreciate it! :)